# Flip integral boundaries of Delta function to get contradiction

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Look at this equation:

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dy\delta\left(x-y\right)f(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dxf(x)$

> If I flip integration boundaries of both integrals, minus symbols cancel, we have:

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dy\delta\left(x-y\right)f(y)=\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}dx\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}dy\delta\left(x-y\right)f(y)=\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}dxf(x)=-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dxf(x)$

Which gives us a contradiction, I think I have abused The Fundamental Theorem to flip the boundaries of delta function. I wonder why it is wrong, where is the problem.

Comment: $\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}dy\delta(x-y)f(y)=-f(x)$, not $f(x)$ as you wrote. So there is no paradox whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is due to the fact that $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}dx'\delta(x-x')=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx'\delta(x-x')=-1$ You only missed this small detail in your calculations.

Everything is fine with flipping integration boundaries!

Also I would have used the term contradiction instead of paradox, it is usually the word used to designate such results.